# SQLException is not propagated to the main thread - Clojure

Tags: postgresql, concurrency, clojure, jvm, future

I'm having issue when running a query against Postgres. If the query takes more than 10 seconds or so, an SQLException occurs as bellow

```
com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@33d2d0dc handling a throwable.: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:326)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:428)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:354)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:169)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:117)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:1418)
at clojure.java.jdbc$execute_query_with_params.invokeStatic(jdbc.clj:993)
at clojure.java.jdbc$execute_query_with_params.invoke(jdbc.clj:987)
at clojure.java.jdbc$db_query_with_resultset_STAR_.invokeStatic(jdbc.clj:1016)
at clojure.java.jdbc$db_query_with_resultset_STAR_.invoke(jdbc.clj:996)
at clojure.java.jdbc$reducible_query$reify__15393.reduce(jdbc.clj:1272)
at clojure.core$reduce.invokeStatic(core.clj:6544)
at clojure.core$reduce.invoke(core.clj:6527)
at cenx.constellation.common$reducible__GT_chan$fn__978.invoke(common.clj:103)
at clojure.core$binding_conveyor_fn$fn__4676.invoke(core.clj:1938)
at clojure.lang.AFn.call(AFn.java:18)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.receiveChar(PGStream.java:290)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1963)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:300)
... 19 more
```

for now I just want to be able to notify my main thread that something has happened. My block of code is as follows

```
(defn func (
[coll name]
    (let [ch (async/chan 100)]
        (future (if (not (Thread/interrupted))
            (try
                (let [  _ (log/info "Start Reading from" name)
                        i (reduce (fn [i v]
                                    (when (zero? (mod i 10000))
                                        (log/debug "row[" i "]: " name))
                                    (if (nil? v)
                                        (log/warn "skipping")
                                    (async/>!! ch [i v]))
                                    (inc i))
                            0 coll)
                        _ (log/info "End Reading, read" i "rows from" name)]
                (async/close! ch))
            (catch SQLException se
                (log/info "SQLException " (.getMessage se))
                (throw (SQLException. "SQLException in my catch block")))
            (finally
                (log/info "Thread is not interrupted")))
        (throw (InterruptedException. "Thread got interrupted"))))
    ch)))
```

Although the exception is catched in the worker thread, the main thread doesn't catch the exception I'm throwing from inside the catch block. I'm new to clojure and would appreciate any comments on this

**EDIT:** I'm adding the method I use to create and configure the connection pool

`(defn- pool
   [{:keys [subprotocol host port db user pool] :as _spec}]
   {:datasource
   (doto (ComboPooledDataSource.)
     (.setJdbcUrl (str "jdbc:" subprotocol "://" host ":" port "/" db))
     (.setUser user)
     (.setPassword (get-postgres-password))
     (.setInitialPoolSize (:min-size pool))
     (.setMinPoolSize (:min-size pool))
     (.setMaxPoolSize (:max-size pool))
     (.setMaxConnectionAge (* 1 60 60))
     (.setMaxIdleTime (* 1/2 60 60))
     (.setMaxIdleTimeExcessConnections (* 5 60))
     (.setIdleConnectionTestPeriod (* 10 60)))})`

see [here](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuration) for existing configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more research I realized that when using **future** block in **Clojure**, all exceptions are swallowed unless the **future** get **derefed**. So I could resolve my issue by updating my **defn** as bellow and dereferencing the **future** in another **defn** later on.

```
(defn func
([coll name]
(let [ch (async/chan 100)
future-f (future
               (let [i (reduce (fn [i v]
                                 (when (zero? (mod i 10000))
                                   (log/debug " row[" i "]: " name))

                                 (if (nil? v)
                                   (log/warn "skipping")
                                   (async/>!! ch [i v]))
                                 (inc i))
                               0 coll)
                     _ (log/info "End Reading, read" i "rows from" name)]
                 (async/close! ch)))]
 [ch future-f])))
```

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve any internally thrown Exceptions, add a [`ConnectionEventListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/ConnectionEventListener.html) / [`StatementEventListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/StatementEventListener.html) to your [`NewPooledConnection`](https://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/apidocs/com/mchange/v2/c3p0/impl/NewPooledConnection.html#addConnectionEventListener-javax.sql.ConnectionEventListener-).

Comment: I've added the way the connection pool is configured to my original question. would you please elaborate a little how I can integrate what you mentioned into my method?